# How can I set up an authenticated encrypted SMTP server?

Tags: security, server, mail, smtp, ssl

I'd like to set up authenticated, encrypted SMTP on my remote Ubuntu server, how do I do that?

It's just a personal server, so I'd like a cheap option, i.e. not buying SSL certs - self-signed will do for now at least.

Update: I'm a little tied to exim as I've got some other stuff configured in that.

Comment: FYI, you can get free SSL certs that will validate in most browsers (updated WinXP's IE6, Firefox 2.0, OS X) from http://startssl.com. It's what I'm using on all my sites.

Comment: Are none of the supplied answers suitable?  If they are, please mark them as such.

Comment: Sorry, lost track of this a long time ago! I am not using this setup now so can't say which would have worked, but have accepted the top answer as it looks helpful even though it wasn't exim based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/). This is a mail server which is very easy to set up (in my opinion). You'll find some useful documents:

- [Postfix SMTP AUTH (and TLS) HOWTO](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/)
- [Postfix TLS Readme](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)
- [Postfix-Wiki](http://postfix.wiki.xs4all.nl/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Postfix documentation site](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html)

Those documents cover the basic setup of Postfix. If you encounter problems you should come back (or better, ask Superuser).

Comment: Thanks, but I should have specified that I'm a little tied to exim as we've got some other stuff configured in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using postfix and dovecot packages. There are lots of detailed instructions available. Just to mention a few:

http://johnny.chadda.se/article/mail-server-howto-postfix-and-dovecot-with-mysql-and-tlsssl-postgrey-and-dspam/

http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-mail-server-setup-with-postfix-dovecot-sasl-squirrel-mail.html

http://rimuhosting.com/support/settingupemail.jsp?mta=postfix

http://www.linuxmail.info/

Answer (score 1):

Install dovecot-postfix package and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

One place to get started with encrypted authentication for exim is here:

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/280/HowTo_Setup_Basic_SMTP_AUTH_in_Exim4

Answer (score 1):

Install the `exim4-daemon-light` package. Debconf will ask you some questions about the setup of the server.  The installation should auto-generate some self-signed certificates, if it doesn't use the `/usr/share/doc/exim4-base/examples/exim-gencert` script to generate one, or do it by hand.

Install `sasl2-bin` to get a saslauth daemon. Then read `/usr/share/doc/exim4-config/README.Debian.gz`, in particular the 2.2.2. and 2.3. sections.

This will explain the rest, but briefly, edit `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros` to include

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = true
```

Comment: of course, you probably already have the exim package installed.